# Как получить расширения img в js?

Tags: javascript, html

столкнулся с вопросом получения расширениям изображениям.

Обрезать ссылку не выйдет так как некоторые изображения имеют ссылку такую -

`"https://c.hit.ua/hit?i=35274&g=0&x=2&s=1&c=1&t=-180&w=1536&h=864&d=24&0.8902127423959483&r=https%3A//www.google.com/&u=https%3A//askdev.ru/q/kak-proverit-tip-fayla-mime-s-pomoschyu-javascript-pered-zagruzkoy-18453/"`

как можно получить тип изображения ?

```js
let image = new Image();
image.src = "https://c.hit.ua/hit?i=35274&g=0&x=2&s=1&c=1&t=-180&w=1536&h=864&d=24&0.8902127423959483&r=https%3A//www.google.com/&u=https%3A//askdev.ru/q/kak-proverit-tip-fayla-mime-s-pomoschyu-javascript-pered-zagruzkoy-18453/";

console.log(image.type); // должен получиться вывод - gif
```

Comment: Интересно, а можно ли посмотреть Content-Type у той ссылки?

Comment: каким образом ?

Comment: Если бы вы могли сделать запрос, например через [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) и в объекте-ответ посмотреть на значение заголовка Content-Type

Comment: Немогли бы показать пример запроса и получения ответа ?

Comment: Content-Type у картинки может быть текстом, или даже(не помню точно) вообще отсутствовать. встречал такое с серверов фейсбука.

Comment: посмотрел щас в панели разработчика все свойства у изображения, тип нигде не нашел. Возможно плохо смотрел. Либо тогда на js не возможно определить тип картинки. На стороне сервера можно php перебрать вызовы функций типа imagecreatefrompng() и смотреть какой будет успешным. а  с Content-Type сервера фейсбука не дружат, отдают вроде текст у картинок ))

Comment: @Андрюха есть расширения в Chrome - Image Downloader , и он выводит тип изображения даже если в ссылке нету его , нету мыслей как это сделать ?

Comment: можно рассматривать изображение как текст..первыми символами вашего изображения являются символы `GIF89a`..можно сделать вывод, что это гифка. :)

Comment: имхо CORS  мешает,  Content-Type не определить из-за этого, как и к содержимому имеджа не получить доступ. (( тупик.

Comment: вот тут еще почитать можно про CORS-proxy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors может поможет, но там сервер надо использовать вроде, а у вас условие - чисто js.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно будет сделать запрос HEAD для получения заголовков. Вот еще одна простая версия, использующая fetch API, может выглядеть так:

```js
function getImgContentType (img_src) {
  return fetch(img_src, { method: 'HEAD' })
    .then(response => response.headers.get('Content-type'))
}
```

И использование будет:

```js
getImgContentType(img_src).then(type => {
  console.log(type)
})
```

Comment: делаю вызов функции но в консоль ничего не выводит.

Comment: @IgorBiyar, CORS не мешает? Смотрите на запрос в инспекторе браузера на вкладке сетей

Comment: делаю в онлайн редакторе js - https://jsfiddle.net/fLku8he0/58/ ,

в инспекторе cетей выдаёт ошибку - Falied to load response data : no data found.

Comment: можно на стороне сервера написать скрипт, который будет делать запрос, и получать тип изображения

Comment: это должно быть на стороне клиента через js/jQuery